# How to sort table value using PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch MySQL table value using one order using MySQL and PHP. I am providing my table below.

db_cat:

```
id     cat_name   cat_id     order_no

1       aaa        10          1

2       ggg        10          30

3        fff       10           11


4      sss         10           12

5      ddd         10            5
```

Here I am trying to fetch data as per order_no column value by using the query :

```
select * from db_cat where cat_id='10' order by order_no asc
```

but it is giving me the wrong order data like(11,12,30,1,5) where I should get the data like this order(`1,5,11,12,30`).

my order_no datatype is `varchar`.

Comment: Change `order_no` datatype to `int`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a cast in order by

```
select * from db_cat where cat_id='10' order by cast(order_no as int) asc
```